# Add uri to listview if its file path exists

Tags: android, listview

I have 3 image uri's in my `String string_uri` and I add them on my listview using a for loop. But I only want to add them if their file path exists.

```
ListView lv;
ArrayList<Uri> array_list = new ArrayList<Uri>();
ArrayAdapter<Uri> array_adapter;

Oncreate of my fragment..

array_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Uri> (getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_list);
lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_sfai);
lv.setAdapter(array_adapter);

String string_uri = "content://media/external/images/media/5042, content://media/external/images/media/5043, content://media/external/images/media/5044";

for(String image_uri : string_uri.split(", ")) {

                Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse(image_uri),null,null,null,null);
                c.moveToNext();
                String path = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA));
                c.close();
                File filePath = new File(path);

                if (filePath.exists()) {

                        Uri image_Uri = Uri.parse(image_uri);
                        array_list.add(image_Uri);
                        sfFive.onGetUri(array_list);
                        array_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
}
```

Everything works perfectly. But if I delete for example, the image of `content://media/external/images/media/5042` in my gallery then I open the app, my app crashes. Here's my LogCat:

```
02-23 02:48:26.536: E/AndroidRuntime(32245): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-23 02:48:26.536: E/AndroidRuntime(32245): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
02-23 02:48:26.536: E/AndroidRuntime(32245):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:424)
02-23 02:48:26.536: E/AndroidRuntime(32245):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
02-23 02:48:26.536: E/AndroidRuntime(32245):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
02-23 02:48:26.536: E/AndroidRuntime(32245):    at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:114)
02-23 02:48:26.536: E/AndroidRuntime(32245):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
02-23 02:48:26.536: E/AndroidRuntime(32245):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
02-23 02:48:26.536: E/AndroidRuntime(32245):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
```

Comment: please post all the logcat ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U need to apply a condition if cursor doesn't have any data instead of directly using moveToNext with ur code...

```
 if(cursor.moveToFirst()){ // cursor.moveToNext() also can help u
 //then ur code...

 }
```

Comment: Where should I put it? after the for statement of before the c.moveToNext();?

Comment: before using cursor obj ,u have to put this condn check..in ur case just after cur init line.